# could not get full string when send to php file from ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
<!--viewservice.php-->
```

On blur i send data to get_service_category.php with the help of ajax function getservice_search. Before sending i alert the variable it give full string as Buff & Gelcoat [Acrylic Nail Enhancement] but when it is posted to get_service_category.php and then echoed back to the page it just print Buff after that it is trimmed

```
 <label>Search Service</label>
            <input type='text' name='country' id="select_service" value='' class='auto' onblur="getservice_search(this.value)"/>
            <img src="img/icons/search-50.png" height="22" width="22" style="padding-left:5px;margin-bottom:-5px;cursor:pointer;" id="search" alt="Search" title="Click To Search" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>    
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(function() {
                            //autocomplete
                            $(".auto").autocomplete({
                            source: "search_services.php",
                            minLength: 1
                            });                

                            });
                            </script>
<script type="text/javascript">                            
 function getservice_search(x)
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

var select_service = document.getElementById("select_service").value;
alert(select_service);

xmlhttp.open("GET","get_service_category.php?select_service="+select_service,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

enter code here

<!--get_service_category.php -->

<?php
include('../config/connect.php');
    include('unset_super_admin.php');
function clean($str) 
    {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

if(isset($_GET['service_category']))
{
    $service_category = $_GET['service_category'];
$sql  ="select * from services where service_cat_id='$service_category' ";
}


else if($_GET['select_service'])
{
    $select_service=clean($_GET["select_service"]);
$sql  ="select * from services where service_name='$select_service' ";  
}
else if($_GET['select_service']=="")
{

$sql  ="select * from services";    
}
$result_services = mysql_query($sql);
if($result_services)
{
    echo $select_service;
?>
    <table style="text-align:center;" class="viewcustomer">
             <tr>
             <th>Id</th>
             <th>Service Name</th>
             <th>Price</th>
             <th>Action</th>

             </tr>
<?php

    while($rowresult=mysql_fetch_array($result_services))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$rowresult[service_id]</td>";
        echo "<td>$rowresult[service_name]</td>";
        echo "<td>$rowresult[service_price]</td>";
        echo '<td><a href="edit_services.php?service_id=' . $rowresult['service_id'] .'" "><Img src="img/icons/button_edit.gif" title="EDIT" alt="EDIT SERVICE" /> </a></td>';
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: __sql injection warning__ you need to escape ___EVERY___ request not some of them :)

Comment: for that i used mysql_real_escape_string
what else should i add

Comment: Additional note: why do you use getservice_search when you have jquery autocomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You neglected to URL-encode your values properly – `&` in a query string separates parameters from each other, so `?select_service=Buff & Gelcoat…` would mean one parameter named `select_service` with value `Buff`, and then a second parameter named `Gelcoat…`.

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the value before putting it into the query string.